# Listview display repeated items when click

Tags: android, listview

I am working on where user click on the item in the listview , it will display bus time inside the item.

I am not sure what went wrong. When it click , it displays a item in a list view. But when i scroll the listview, it will display the same bus time from previous item. I had read a few solutions from stackoverflow however , I had not solve this problem.

I hope to get some advices to solve this issue.

[The text will appear when being clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iktu0.jpg)

[Same text appear when scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRM21.jpg)

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter
{

    ArrayList<BusRoute>busList ;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        busList=objects;
        this.resource=resource;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView buscode;
        TextView businfo;
        TextView bookmark;
        TextView firstBusTime;

    }




    @Override
    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_route_activity_listview,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.buscode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buscode);
            holder.businfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
            holder.bookmark = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
            holder.firstBusTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstBusTime);

        }

        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final BusRoute map = busList.get(position);
        holder.buscode.setText(map.getBusStopCode());
        holder.businfo.setText(map.getRoad() + "\n" + map.getDescription());

            //when user select on the particular item in the listview
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.firstBusTime.setText("Yo");

            }

        });


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

BusRoute Class

```
public class BusRoute {
private String BusStopCode;
private String Road;
private String Description;

public String getBusStopCode() {
    return BusStopCode;
}

public void setBusStopCode(String busStopCode) {
    BusStopCode = busStopCode;
}


public String getRoad() {
    return Road;
}

public void setRoad(String road) {
    Road = road;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

}
```

Adapter that is being called

```
public class BusRouteTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<BusRoute>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<BusRoute> doInBackground(String... params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<BusRoute> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Adapter a = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),       R.layout.activity_bus_route, result);
        lv.setAdapter(a);
```

Comment: Please post your BusRoute class.

Comment: `final BusRoute map = busList.get(position);
        holder.buscode.setText(map.getBusStopCode());......` add this in your `if(convertView == null)` section .

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter
{

    ArrayList<BusRoute>busList ;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        busList=objects;
        this.resource=resource;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView buscode;
        TextView businfo;
        TextView bookmark;
        TextView firstBusTime;

    }




    @Override
    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_route_activity_listview,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.buscode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buscode);
            holder.businfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
            holder.bookmark = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
            holder.firstBusTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstBusTime);

        }

        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final BusRoute map = busList.get(position);
        holder.buscode.setText(map.getBusStopCode());
        holder.businfo.setText(map.getRoad() + "\n" + map.getDescription());

            //when user select on the particular item in the listview
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(holder.firstBusTime,map));


        return convertView;
    }


    class Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    BusRoute Data;
    TextView timeView;
    Listener(TextView timeView,BusRoute Data)
    {
    this.Data = Data;
    this.timeView = timeView;
    }
     @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            // Set your test here use dataobject like
            // timeView.firstBusTime.setText(data.getBustTIme());
             timeView.firstBusTime.setText("Yo");
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, same output result appear.

Answer (score 0):

*Change Your getView() method as following*

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_route_activity_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.buscode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buscode);
            holder.businfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
            holder.bookmark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
            holder.firstBusTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstBusTime);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final BusRoute map = busList.get(position);
        holder.buscode.setText(""+map.getBusStopCode());
        holder.businfo.setText(map.getRoad() + "\n" + map.getDescription());
        holder.firstBusTime.setText(map.getTime());
        //when user select on the particular item in the listview
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                holder.firstBusTime.setText("Yo");
                map.setTime("Yo");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

*Problem is you are calling `textview.settext()` inside `onclick`, instead you should be updating the model item content value.
In your case you can make a new field in your `BusRoute` class e.g. `String time;` and you will be creating `getters` and `setters`. Then set the textview value like above.*

*Hope it will work.*